# How to maintain an icon font from SVG files

Tags: css, web-applications, svg, fonts, icon-fonts

We have an icon font (and relevant CSS code) for an icon font pack. However we  need to add more icons to the pack or edit some of the current ones.

The question is: how can we do it without having an expensive font-design software? We've bought [Glyph Mini](http://www.glyphsapp.com/glyphs-mini) for Mac but it would be great if there was a free service that you could just go there, upload your SVG files and get a new font file. That way you could have a directory full of SVG files and when you edit or add something, you can "compile" your own font. It would be even better if there was such compiler that we could use from command line. However, I haven't seen such tools.

Anyone aware of neat free solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use gulp-iconfont or even svgicons2svgfont/svg2ttf/ttf2eot/ttf2woff/ttf2woff2 for pure CLI toolchain, see https://github.com/nfroidure/svgiconfont/blob/master/package.json#L7.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discovered IcoMoon app. It is free and I think it is great for what you need. Here is the link: http://icomoon.io/app/

Answer (score 1):

I usually use: [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/)

You can combine free fonts and also add yours, give it a try,